# Divisor of $2^{kp}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm trying to find a divisor $2^{kp}-1$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is a prime number. I know that $2^p-1$ is a divisor but I don't understand why that is the case. 
 
 If someone could explain why this is so that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's beacause $2^{kp}=(2^p)^k$ and that, for any $m\in\mathbb N$,$$m^k-1=(m-1)(m^{k-1}+m^{k-2}+\cdots+1),$$from which it follows that $m-1\mid m^k-1$. So, replacing $m$ with $2^p$, you get that $2^p-1\mid 2^{kp}-1$. The fact that $p$ is prime is not relevant.